# Failed: Cannot read property 'findElementsOverride' of undefined

Tags: protractor

I have the following test:

```
        it('diplays the currency and description of a valid account', function () {
            common.setValueForInput("CH3809000000911058770", page.inputs.css.zahlungKontoIban).then(
                function () {
                    return element(page.buttons.empfaengerKontoValidieren).click();
                })
                .then(function () {
                    return expect(element(by.id("zahlungKontoIbanFehler")).isDisplayed())
                        .toBeFalsy('an error message must not be shown when the accounts are different');
                })
                .then(function(){
                    browser.pause();
                expect(element(by.id("zielwaehrung")).getAttribute("innerHTML"))
                    .toContain('CHF', 'the currency for CH3809000000911058770 is CHF')
                expect(element(by.id("empfaengerName")).getAttribute("innerHTML"))
                    .toContain('Test Bezeichnung 2', 'the description for CH3809000000911058770 is Test Bezeichnung 2')
                })
        });
```

it fails with the stack trace:

```
AccountClosing - UI009.1 account validation account validation diplays the currency and description of a valid account
Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'findElementsOverride' of undefined
Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'findElementsOverride' of undefined
at C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:134:20
at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
Error
at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:382:21)
at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as getInnerHtml] (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:78:17)
at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as getInnerHtml] (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:711:7)
at C:\beam-app\accountClosing\ui009\e2e\accountClosing_ui009_1_e2e_test.ts:94:59
at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: Run it("diplays the currency and description of a valid account") in control flow
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
at attemptAsync (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1819:24)
at QueueRunner.run (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1774:9)
at QueueRunner.execute (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1762:10)
at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:627:35)
at Spec.execute (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:353:10)
at Object.fn (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:2360:37)
at attemptAsync (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1819:24)
at QueueRunner.run (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1774:9)
at C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1801:16
From asynchronous test:
    Error
at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\beam-app\accountClosing\ui009\e2e\accountClosing_ui009_1_e2e_test.ts:83:13)
at addSpecsToSuite (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:743:25)
at Env.describe (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:713:7)
at jasmineInterface.describe (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3219:18)
at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\beam-app\accountClosing\ui009\e2e\accountClosing_ui009_1_e2e_test.ts:65:9)
at addSpecsToSuite (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:743:25)
at Env.describe (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:713:7)
at jasmineInterface.describe (C:\Users\roonm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3219:18)
at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\beam-app\accountClosing\ui009\e2e\accountClosing_ui009_1_e2e_test.ts:36:5)
```

the position line 94:59 is the statement `getInnerHtml()` of

```
expect(element(page.zielwaehrung).getInnerHtml())
                        .toContain('CHF', 'the currency for CH3809000000911058770 is CHF')
```

I put the `browser.pause()` to check that the elements are indeed present and they are.

What does this message mean and how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from too many `beforeAll` calls

I mistakenly thought that `beforeAll` applied to the `describe` in which it is called. It turns out this is not the case and that when you make 5 calls to `beforeAll` with a `browser.get` inside it messeses up something.

I replaced the multiple calls with a single call to `beforeEach` and now everything works nicely.

Comment: Sounds quite weird, could you make a reproducible sample and [open up a github issue with protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`getInnerHtml` method is deprecated now.use `getAttribute("innerHTML")` instead.

Comment: Thats another way of doing it.. But `getInnerHtml()` should also work right?

Comment: `getInnerHtml` was deprecated recently (as of version 4.0.0). See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400. Could you use `.getText()` instead?